# Can't update part number field via php in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a script to update my record via php in mySQL.  All of the fields can be updated except $part_no.

I can't figure out why "part_no" will not update.

Appreciate any help.

```
<?php session_start();


$type=$_POST['type'];
$part_no=$_POST['part_no'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$artwork=$_POST['artwork'];
$min=$_POST['min'];
$max=$_POST['max'];

$db="naturan8_hero";

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "XXXXXXX", "XXXXXX");
if (! $link)
die("Couldn't connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db($db , $link)
or die("Couldn't open $db: ".mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query(" UPDATE cartons_current SET type='$type' , part_no='$part_no',     description='$description',artwork='$artwork', min='$min' , max='$max' WHERE part_no='$part_no' ");

if($query) {
header("location: inv_fc_edit_success.php?part_no=" . urlencode($part_no));
}else{
header("location: inv_fc_edit_fail.php");
}

?>
```

Here is the form for editing:

```
<?php
$record = $_POST['part_no'];


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$result=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM cartons_current WHERE part_no='$record'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$type=mysql_result($result,$i,"type");
$part_no=mysql_result($result,$i,"part_no");
$description=mysql_result($result,$i,"description");
$artwork=mysql_result($result,$i,"artwork");
$min=mysql_result($result,$i,"min");
$max=mysql_result($result,$i,"max");
?>


<div id="fcICON">Hero</div>
<div id="titleWRAP">
<div id="newTITLE">Edit Part Number</div>
<div id="newINS">This area is designated for editing a part number. Please <b>be careful and alert </b>to your changes, because they are immediately posted.</div>
</div>
<div class="form_hero_new">
<form id="form_editX" method="POST" action="inv_fc_edit2.php"   onfocus="this.value=''">
  <input type="hidden" name="type" type="text" value="FC">
  <input type="hidden" name="part_no" value="<? echo "$record" ?>">
  <div style="width: 500px; height:63px;float:left;">
    <div style="width: 165px; height:65px;float:left;">
      <div id="heroLABEL" style="width:150px">Part Number</div>
      <div id="newPN">
        <textarea name="part_no"  maxlength="20" minlength="6" type="text" style="width: 130px;color:#FFFF00"><? echo "$part_no"?></textarea>
      </div>
```

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I will change to the statements once I'm done, but I wanted to get this resolved first.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Comment: `mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());` and see what it gives you

Comment: How do you change the part_no when your WHERE clause is selecting by it? Shouldn't you do WHERE part_no = '$old_part_no' or similar?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by set.  The record is already been made.  The client searches the record via part_no and then is edited in a different window.

Comment: @incarnate part_no is the unique ID field. I don;t want to create a new  record but edit the existing one in  mySQl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting `part_no` to its existing value, which will make no change:

```sql
UPDATE cartons_current SET part_no='$part_no' WHERE part_no='$part_no'
```

Comment: Is there a particular place where I should place this?

Comment: @Erik: No, that's an abbreviation of what you already have to demonstrate my point.  What value do you want to update the `part_no` to?

Comment: I'm echoing part_no in a textarea field so it can be changed.  I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @Erik: You're using the same field name `part_no` for both the old value in the `hidden` field (from `$record`) and the new value in the the `textarea`.  Make them distinct: e.g. change the name of the `hidden` field to, say, `old_part_no` then refer to that in the `WHERE` clause of your `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a part number such as `PART001` and you change it to `PART002` in your form, you will be overwriting any existing `PART002` data with actual `PART001` data.

I would consider adding an `id` column and using that in the `WHERE` clause.